# Why do I have one nav li float below all my other nav li's when using float:right

Tags: html, css

I don't think my nav li's are collapsing but I've been spending two days researching and trying to fix the problem. Bascially my Contact nav li element is hanging right below About nav li. I want them to all display all on one line whenever i resize the browser screen to 700px. Here is my relevant code:

HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Randy Goldsmith</h1>
    <h4>Front End  Web Developer</h4>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS
    /***********************
    Navigation
    ***********************/

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
/***********************
Heading
***********************/

header {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px){
    /***********************
  Header
  ***********************/
  nav {
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
  }

  .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }


}
```

My codepenio where my page is: http://codepen.io/duel_drawer8/pen/xOLErV?editors=1100

Comment: can you include a screenshot to describe the issue you're seeing please, it appears to be displaying correctly inline when i view your codepen. http://imgur.com/NFYsBkJ

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION:**

You need to **remove** the property **`width: 50%;`** from your **nav selector** in your **media query**.

*Replace:*

```
nav {
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
  }
```

*With:*

```
nav {
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
  }
```

---

**EXPLANATION:**

> One floated element next to another floated element can’t stick out
>   past the edge of its container.

The problem lies in your floated elements since they no longer fit their container in that specific viewport. That's why your last element is hanging right below.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
#wrapper {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
}
.logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background: green;
  border-color: green;
}
h1,
h3 {
  color: white;
}
nav a,
a:hover {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
/***********************
Navigation
***********************/

nav {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
/***********************
Heading
***********************/

header {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
}
/***********************
Footer
***********************/

footer {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
footer img {
  width: 6%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
/***********************
Portfolio
***********************/

#gallery {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
#gallery li a p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  /***********************
  Two Column Layout
  ***********************/
  #primary {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
  }
  #secondary {
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
  }
  /***********************
  Portfolio
  ***********************/
  #gallery li {
    width: 28.3333%;
  }
  #gallery li:nth-child(3n + 1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  /***********************
  Header
  ***********************/
  nav {
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    margin-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 33.3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Randy Goldsmith</h1>
    <h3>Front End  Web Developer</h3>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <ul id="gallery">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/wi2l9sni9/Screenshot_7.png">
          <p>Weather App</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/wi2l9sni9/Screenshot_7.png">
          <p>Weather App</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://s6.postimg.org/wi2l9sni9/Screenshot_7.png">
          <p>Weather App</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/duel_drawer8" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/4-128.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/randy.goldsmith.10" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/3-128.png">
    </a>
    <a href="www.linkedin.com/in/randygoldsmith" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/9-128.png">
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/Dueldrawer8" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-network-7/50/29-128.png">
    </a>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Randy Goldsmith</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```